# Where's the Device Manager in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10, devices

In the [community Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DeviceManager) which has this notice:

> Needs Updating
>   This article needs updating to include the latest versions of Ubuntu.

It says it is located here: `System > Administration > Device Manager`.

But such a menu hierarchy doesn't exist anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is an abandoned package, [last available in Ubuntu 11.04](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/gnome-device-manager/)

You can try *hardinfo* which offers much the same information:  `sudo apt-get install hardinfo`